# Never show up in QuickView all files that are or will be present in a folder recursively

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible in Windows 10 to prevent all present and future files in a folder, recursively, from ever showing up in QuickView?

Comment: QuickView hasn't been part of Windows for over 20 years. What are you talking about?

Comment: Are you talking about **QUick Access**? If so are you talking about `Frequent Folders` or `Recent Files`? Files are excluded from `Recent Files` by extension, not by location.